# GridView Access Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, gridview, oledb

I have a GridView control that I would like to display the rows of a table (cartTable), based on the field 'orderNo' which is stored in a integer 'intOrderNo', how can i configure my data source to do as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
-connect to the access file
-set your query and your WHERE clause
-execute it
-then bind it to your grid

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\YOUR_ACCESS_FILE_PATH");
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM cartTable WHERE orderNo = " + intOrderNo , conn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

//Bind your grid
this.gridView1.DataSource = dt;
this.gridView1.DataBind();
```